# React updating state for validation always a step behind even when i set a callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to validate a form with two inputs. If each input has at least a character or more, the button should be enabled. 
The problem here is that the state is always one step behind. I handled validation in the callback but it still didnt solve the problem. Please help anyone!

```
state = {
    name : '',
    nameIsValid: false,
    zip : '',
    zipIsValid: false,
    allIsValid: false
  }
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name] : event.target.value,
    }, ()=>this.handleValidation())
  }
handleValidation = () => {
    if(this.state.name.length > 0){
      this.setState({nameIsValid : true})
    } else {
      this.setState({nameIsValid: false})
    }

    if(this.state.zip.length > 0){
      this.setState({zipIsValid : true})
    } else {
      this.setState({zipIsValid: false})
    }

    if(this.state.nameIsValid && this.state.zipIsValid){
      this.setState({allIsValid: true})
    }
  }
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Name: <input name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.name}/><br />
        Zip: <input name="zip" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.zip}/><br />
        <button disabled={!this.state.allIsValid}>Proceed</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's down to the multiple `setStates` you're using. You can actually make your code a little more concise and make this work at the same time.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    name: '',
    nameIsValid: false,
    zip: '',
    zipIsValid: false,
    allIsValid: false
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {

    // Destructure the name and value from the target
    const { target: { name, value } } = event;

    this.setState({

      // Set only that changed input valid property to true or false
      // depending on whether it has length
      [`${name}IsValid`]: value.length > 0 || false,
      [name]: value
    }, this.validate);
  }

  validate = () => {

    // Then just set the allIsValid property based on the
    // whether the other properties are both true 
    this.setState((state) => ({
      allIsValid: state.nameIsValid && state.zipIsValid
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      Name:
      <input name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.name}/>
      <br />
      Zip:
      <input name="zip" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.zip} />
      <br />
      <button disabled={!this.state.allIsValid}>Proceed</button>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thankyou! I think the problem was that i checked this.state.name.length to change the state isNameValid. You have used the target.value.length directly to change the state isNameValid, which has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
   name: '',
   zip: ''
 }



handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({
     [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  });
}

validateForm = () => {
  return this.state.name.length > 0 && this.state.zip.length > 0;
}

<button disabled={!this.validateForm()}>Proceed</button>
```

Comment: Very insightful to know that this could be done without changing state in the validate function. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: It just happened that I did this in my project not too long ago and it works perfectly. The way you did is a lot more complicated and I think it cannot work unless you use previousState when you change the state, such as this.setState({ previousState =>  if(previousState.name.length > 0) {...